# Error "package javax.faces.bean does not exist" at import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, netbeans

I am studying JSF from [Oracle online tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnadr/index.html). While building its example "hello1" on netbeans it gives the following error at the line `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;`:

> package javax.faces.bean does not exist

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: If you added glassfish as a server/target to Netbeans, you should have either `jsf-api.jar` or `javaee.jar` in your libraries for the project.  Only one of these jars are needed and they contain the package you get the error about (some more [links](https://community.jboss.org/thread/65871?start=0&tstart=0) to [read](http://forums.java.net/node/645343))

Comment: @Levon Did you solve this problem? I'm running into the same issue and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @AlienBishop Hi, I didn't recall asking this question in spite of this showing me as the questioner. When I look at the edit history, it shows me editing the question but it shows user 1446298 as the originator of this question - you may want to ping him/her. Good luck.

Comment: @AlienBishop yes, following answer solve my problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add these 2 dependency in your project's pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

This will solve your dependency problem.

Comment: More recent dependency:  `<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>`

Answer (score 9):

You have to add javax.faces.api jar file to your project.
You can find this library [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.1).

After downloading this file, you have to import that into your project and add it to your artifact.

Answer (score 2):

For gradle :

'com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.2.8'

'com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.2.8'

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Netbeans** you can search for the library javax.faces.jar in the same folder of this application, you may find it in a folder like this: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\enterprise\modules\ext\jsf-2_2.

Now, right click  on yourProject/libraries in **Netbeans** then choose **Add JAR/Folder...** command to add javax.faces.jar file.

[Adding javax.faces.jar library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ZYA.jpg)

From the same popup menu you can use **Add Library** and add **Java EE from GlassFish**

[Adding Java EE from GlassFish library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwJRg.jpg)

Good luck.