# run web application - error: package javax.faces.bean does not exist

Tags: java, web-applications, runtime-error

I'm newly at web application.
I tried run easy web application program. After running

```
javac -d WEB-INF/classes WEB-INF/classes/bigjava/*.java
```

I had output:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/Desktop/Big JAVA/bj4_code/ch24/time$ javac -d WEB-INF/classes WEB-INF/classes/bigjava/*.java
WEB-INF/classes/bigjava/TimeBean.java:6: error: package javax.faces.bean does not exist
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
                       ^
WEB-INF/classes/bigjava/TimeBean.java:7: error: package javax.faces.bean does not exist
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
                       ^
WEB-INF/classes/bigjava/TimeBean.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
@ManagedBean
 ^
  symbol: class ManagedBean
WEB-INF/classes/bigjava/TimeBean.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
@SessionScoped
 ^
  symbol: class SessionScoped
4 errors
```

**Code:**

```
package bigjava;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TimeBean
{
   private DateFormat timeFormatter;

   /**
      Initializes the formatter.
   */
   public TimeBean()
   {
      timeFormatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
   }

   /**
      Read-only time property.
      @return the formatted time
   */
   public String getTime()
   {
      Date time = new Date();
      String timeString = timeFormatter.format(time);
      return timeString;
   }
}
```

All class files really placed inside the `WEB-INF/classes` directory.
index.html is into `WEB-INF` and contained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>The time application</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h:form>
         <p>           
            The current time is #{timeBean.time}
         </p>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml is at the same level as `classes` and contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I maybe lose something but I couldn’t figure out what exactly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `javax.faces.api` jar file to your project. You can find this library [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.1).

After downloading this file, you have to import that into your project and add it to your artifact.

refer to this link [Error “package javax.faces.bean does not exist”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18525406)