# how to add jsf to bluemix webstarterapp?

Tags: jsf, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to add JSF to my webstarterapp.

I have created an JSF managed bean, but when compiling the app using the provided `build.xml`, I get the errors:

```
[javac] /Users/snowch/.../Customer.java:8: error: package javax.faces.bean does not exist
[javac] import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
[javac]                        ^
[javac] /Users/snowch/.../Customer.java:9: error: package javax.faces.bean does not exist
[javac] import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
[javac]                        ^
[javac] /Users/snowch/.../Customer.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] @ManagedBean
[javac]  ^
[javac]   symbol: class ManagedBean
[javac] /Users/snowch/.../Customer.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] @RequestScoped
[javac]  ^
[javac]   symbol: class RequestScoped
[javac] 4 errors
[javac] 4 warnings
```

It looks like I need to add the jsf jar to my `dep-jar` folder as it currently isn't there:

```
snowch:csjavatest snowch$ tree dep-jar/
dep-jar/
└── com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxrs.1.1_1.0.1.jar

0 directories, 1 file
```

**Question:** Where can I download the appropriate version of the jsf library jar file?

Comment: I am not sure about your project structure and JSF versions, if at all but this line : `error: package javax.faces.bean does not exist` basically means that the `javax.faces(.api)` jar file is missing on the compile-time class-path. Those things are available on the Maven repository - [**jsf-api**](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/), [**jsf-impl**](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/) or if you are running with a single [**javax.faces**](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/).

Comment: It seems duplicate question asked previously:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961916/error-package-javax-faces-bean-does-not-exist-at-import-javax-faces-bean-manag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I updated the `build.xml` file to add a `pathelement` for `javax.faces.jar` that was sitting in my glassfish installation folder:

```
<path id="classpathDir">
  <pathelement location="bin"/>
  <pathelement location="dep-jar/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxrs.1.1_1.0.1.jar"/>

  <!- added \/ -->
  <pathelement location=
    "/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1//glassfish/modules/javax.faces.jar"/>
  <!- added /\ -->
</path>
```

Answer (score 3):

Below developer works article can help you (it has everything to get started with JSF2) along with required download details of lib files for Bluemix:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-richfaces4/

Although I had never worked on these things,hoping that it this article info may help you.