# "The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path" unresolved by the set of the targeted runtime

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, server

When I created a JSP page in Eclipse Neon, the following error message appeared:

```
"The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path"
```

When I created a Servlet the following error message appeared:

```
"The import javax.faces cannot be resolved"
```

Other answers for the "same" question say there is a common root : the targeted runtime is unselected in the project properties. According to this I have selected the Glassfish 4 server. And I can see the servlet-api.jar in the Java Resources\Libraries\Glassfish Libraries.
The servlet error message disappeared but the JSP one lives on. How could I disappear it as well?

Comment: Not sure but this might help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961916/error-package-javax-faces-bean-does-not-exist-at-import-javax-faces-bean-manag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have reloaded the project and the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

In the configuration POM.xml add the following dependencies, with this the error is corrected

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```